# Java MappedByteBuffer performance getting worse and worse when you change the map size continuously

Tags: java, linux, nio, mappedbytebuffer

Recently I had some tests about Java MappedByteBuffer. I found that if I continuously map the same file and read it, the time spend in reading getting longer and longer. But if I didn't change the map size, It would be faster than the I use the same map size in the map size variation test.

I hava a file "dataFile" in 1GB which filled with Integers.

```
private final File dataFile = new File("~/testfile");
private final int intNum = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 4; // 1GB Integers

@Test
public void writeFile() throws Exception {
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));
    for (int i = 0; i < intNum; i++) {
        dos.writeInt(RandomUtils.nextInt());
    }
    dos.close();
}
```

And a method about reading it

```
// read this dataFile in a loop with fixed map size
private void bufferSizePerformanceTest(final int buffSize) throws Exception {
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(dataFile, "r").getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer buffer;
    final int readPerLoop = buffSize / 4;
    int currentLen = 0;
    int readCount = 0;
    for (int i = 1; ; i++) {
        int i1 = i * buffSize;
        if (i1 >= dataFile.length()) {
            buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, currentLen, dataFile.length() - currentLen);
            for (int j = 0; j < readPerLoop; j++) {
                buffer.getInt();
                readCount++;
            }
            break;
        } else {
            buffer = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, currentLen, buffSize);
            currentLen = i1;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < readPerLoop; j++) {
            buffer.getInt();
            readCount++;
        }
    }
    fc.close();
//        ByteBufferUtil.releaseByteBuffer(buffer);
//        System.gc();
    System.out.println("readCount : " + readCount + " raf buffer size " + getMBytes(buffSize) + " MB : " + stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
}
```

The variation buffSize test

```
private static int getMBytes(int bytes) {
    return bytes / 1024 / 1024;
}

// get the power of 2 by n
private static int getM(int n) {
    return (int) (Math.log10(n) / Math.log10(2));
}

@Test
public void testBuffSizeReadPerformance() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());
    for (int i = 0; i <= getM(1024); i++) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        bufferSizePerformanceTest((int) (Math.pow(2, i) * 1024 * 1024));
    }
}
```

Variation Outputs:

```
14071@LiuzhMacbook.local
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1 MB : 122
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 2 MB : 133
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 4 MB : 29
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 8 MB : 35
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 16 MB : 38
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 32 MB : 124
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 64 MB : 241
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 128 MB : 456
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 256 MB : 1086
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 512 MB : 2458
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 4952
```

The fixed buffSize test:

```
@Test
public void testBuffSizeReadPerformance2() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bufferSizePerformanceTest(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

Output

```
14157@LiuzhMacbook.local
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 127
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 111
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 20
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 17
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 23
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 19
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 21
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 22
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 20
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 33
```

As the 2 tests shows, the time spent in reading with the same buffSize(1024MB) is quite different in 2 tests. The test with fixed buffSize is much faster than the variation test.

My question is:
1. How does this happened, why it will be faster?
2. Does the MappedByteBuffer occupy physical memory? As I see in the ActivityMonitor, it will not occupy physical memory.

Thanks

----- Update -----

The release buffer code:

```
public static void releaseByteBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Cleaner cleaner = ((DirectBuffer) buffer).cleaner();
    cleaner.clean();
}
```

I don't think the cause of this problem is memory usage. Because it has the same output even if I turn on the release code and gc code. Anyway, if is about the memory usage, I set the loop times to 100 in the second test, it should use more memory than the first test, but it's faster than the first one.

----- Update 2 -----

If I turn the buffSize to decrease instead of increase in test 1, the problem disappear.

```
@Test
public void testBuffSizeReadPerformance3() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName());
    for (int i = getM(1024); i >= 0; i--) {
        bufferSizePerformanceTest((int) (Math.pow(2, i) * 1024 * 1024));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
16651@LiuzhMacbook.local
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1024 MB : 101
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 512 MB : 187
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 256 MB : 31
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 128 MB : 30
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 64 MB : 36
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 32 MB : 37
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 16 MB : 37
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 8 MB : 32
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 4 MB : 44
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 2 MB : 34
readCount : 268435456 raf buffer size 1 MB : 55
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't 'changing the map size continuously'.You keep creating *new* maps, and there is no mechanism whereby the mappings are released, including GC, so you are using more and more memory.

You should aim to use as few `MappedByteBuffers` as possible, which may mean you need to make the sizes larger as well.

I don't know what `ByteBufferUtil.releaseByteBuffer(buffer)` does, or where it comes from, but these things of their nature cannot be reliable.

Comment: I would have to state that I don't understand the purpose of your test code, but if you don't change the map size you are probably always getting the same underlying mapped memory rather than another chunk, which saves virtual memory. I don't know what the purpose of changing it would be anyway.

Comment: I want to find is there some affect to the efficiency of reading a file when using different map size, so I write this code. And I want to know if I read a file in 1 GB, what map size I should use.

Comment: The answer to that is always the same. As large as possible. Your test is completely invalidated by being run from within the same process, so you are getting all kinds of in-process/cache effects that wouldn't happen in separate processes. The problem here is mainly your testing methodology, not the results.